# Accessing array values in Meteor Template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this simple array that I pass to the template;

```
Template.incomeTotals.total = function() {
  var array = [];
  array[0] = [100000, 59, 58900];
  return array;
};
```

and then this HTML file;

```
<body>
 <table>
   {{> incomeTotals}}
 </table>
</body>

<template name="incomeTotals">
  {{#each total}}
   <tr>
    <th>{{.0}}</th>
    <th>{{.1}}%</th>
    <th>${{.2}}</th>
   </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

What I am trying to do is get these three values all displayed on the same row, but all the values come out on the second row as `100000,59,58900%`. I saw in a similar question where someone was using the form of `{{#each total.array}}` but I got no output when using that syntax.

**Update:**

Here's what ended up working for anyone else stumbling across this:

```
Template.incomeTotals.total = function() {
  var array = [];
  array[0] = {budgetTotal:100000, achievedAvg:59, sumTotals:58900};
  return array;
};
```

HTML;

```
<body>
 <table>
   {{> incomeTotals}}
 </table>
</body>

<template name="incomeTotals">
  {{#each total}}
   <tr>
    <th>{{budgetTotal}}</th>
    <th>{{achievedAvg}}%</th>
    <th>${{sumTotals}}</th>
   </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

To access arrays by index in Meteor templates:

```
{{myArray.[0]}}
{{myArray.[0].that}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer yet, but try:

```
<template name="incomeTotals">
  {{#each total}}
   <tr>
    <th>{{this[0]}}</th>
    <th>{{this[1]}}%</th>
    <th>${{this[2]}}</th>
   </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: It doesn't like the bracket notation. Also tried this.1 and it doesn't like that either. I've also tried `   array[0] = {budgetTotal:100000, achievedAvg:59, sumTotals:58900};
` and then referencing them by name but that doesn't work either.

Comment: with `{budgetTotal ...}` you have to use in template: `{{budgetTotal}}` did you use that?

Comment: Sending a hash in the array and then referencing them by name like you said worked! I had tried earlier to do `var array = [{name:value, ...}]` and that didn't work using `{{budgetTotal ...}}` but that didn't work. But creating the empty array and then adding the hash to `array[0]` is working. Thanks for the help!